# Mac OSX Change From Zoom to Scroll - Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard 4000

Tags: macos, keyboard

I want to remap the Zoom key to Scroll, and all tutorials I found were for configuring the `Command.xml` in windows and this file does not exist in Mac OSX.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is from this post: [Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 with Mac OS X and Linux](http://blog.philippklaus.de/2012/05/microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000-with-mac-os-x-and-linux/)

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences
mv com.microsoft.keyboard.pref com.microsoft.keyboard.pref.bak
wget http://scottbezek.com/com.microsoft.keyboard.pref
open /Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft\ Keyboard.prefPane
# works.
```

Comment: still not working here...

Comment: This works for me!

Comment: Did not work for me either

Answer (score 0):

[toksea's answer](https://superuser.com/a/594879) was almost there for me. However, I noticed that the file permissions on the downloaded .pref file were not the same as the original .pref file. So, the solution for me (on 10.6.8 Snow Leopard) looked like

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences
mv com.microsoft.keyboard.pref com.microsoft.keyboard.pref.bak
wget http://scottbezek.com/com.microsoft.keyboard.pref
chmod 644 com.microsoft.keyboard.pref
xattr -w com.apple.ResourceFork 286 com.microsoft.keyboard.pref
open /Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft\ Keyboard.prefPane
```

However, you should first verify that the values you use for chmod and xattr will match those for your original com.microsoft.keyboard.pref file, via

```
ls -l@ com.microsoft.keyboard*
```